# How do you pull an attribute from html using vba

Tags: html, vba, web-scraping

I need to pull the sku (CS060120) from this section of html (edit:) Using VBA

tried getAttribute and getElementsbyTag(and Class)Name but I am not able to get the return I am looking for. Anyone know how to do this?

```
<section class="product_options">
    <header>
        <h1>
            60' x 120' NiceRink CS Liner
        </h1>
    </header>
    <vue-product-options 
        v-bind:product-opts="[]" 
        v-bind:configurable-payload="{&quot;product_option&quot;:{&quot;extension_attributes&quot;:{&quot;configurable_item_options&quot;:[]}}}" 
        v-bind:liner-types="{&quot;good&quot;:16,&quot;better&quot;:14,&quot;best&quot;:15}" 
        v-bind:is-folded-or-rolled-liner-sku="false" 
        v-bind:bundle-payload="{&quot;product_option&quot;:{&quot;extension_attributes&quot;:{&quot;bundle_options&quot;:[]}}}" 
        v-bind:tier-prices="[]" 
        v-bind:is-wholesale-only="false" 
        v-bind:prices-index="{}" 
        v-bind:options-map="{}" 
        v-bind:is-configurable="false" 
        v-bind:is-rink-liner="false" 
        v-bind:is-liner-sku="true" 
        v-bind:is-bundle="false" product-type="undefined" price="612" sku="CS060120" image="https://www.nicerink.com/media/catalog/product/l/i/liner_1.jpg" magento-base-url="https://www.nicerink.com" name="60' x 120' NiceRink CS Liner">
    </vue-product-options>
    <div class="product_options_panel package_cta">
        <h3>
            Looking for a full Rink Package?
        </h3>

        <p>
            We've got you covered!
        </p>

        <a class="button dark" href="/rink-builder">
            Rink Packages
        </a>
    </div>
</section>
```

This is what I'm trying:

```
ieDoc.getElementsByClassName("product_options")(0).getAttribute("sku")
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors or just null ? I would try with getElementByxpath("//section[@class='product_options']//vue-product-options").getAttribute("sku")

Comment: @Sureshmani I was get null returns. However, getElementByxpath gives me an Sub or Function not defined error - I have not used that method in the past so perhaps I need a reference for that

Comment: you are right. that's probably not a valid sub. can you try with getElementsByTagName('vue-product-options').getAttribute("sku")

Comment: Dang that gets me "Object doesn't support this property or method" I feel like these are close but just something just slightly off

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    alert($(".sdfv").attr("sku"));
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<vue-product-options class="sdfv" sku="CS060120"></vue-product-options>

<button>Click the button to get sku value</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: My mistake, I tagged VBA but didn't mention it in the comment. I'm trying to pull into excel using vba macro.

Answer (score 0):

Try using attribute selector

```
Debug.Print ie.document.querySelector("[sku]").getAttribute("sku")
```

If you need to be more specific you can add the type selector so it becomes

```
Debug.Print ie.document.querySelector("vue-product-options[sku]").getAttribute("sku")
```

Comment: did you try this?